# Epsilon Induction implies Axiom Of Foundation (Or Regularity)

Tags: set-theory

I know that, given the other Zermelo-Fraenkel Axioms, [Epsilon Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon-induction) is equivalent to the [Axiom Of Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

I've proven that Axiom Of Foundation implies Epsilon Induction, but i can't prove the other implication. Any suggest?

Answer (score 11):

This is similar to Brian's answer but with fewer negations.  Prove, by $\in$-induction on $x$ that "Every set $u$ that contains $x$ (as an element) has an $\in$-minimal member, i.e., there is $y\in u$ with $y\cap u=\varnothing$." The point is that, if $x$ itself isn't a minimal member of $u$, then there is some $x'\in x\cap u$, and you can apply the induction hypothesis to $x'$.

Comment: This is a nice proof really, its very DIRECT. The induction HYPOTHESIS is: $$\forall x \, ([\forall y \in x : \forall z (y \in z \to z \text{ has a minimal})] \to \\\forall u (x \in u \to u \text{ has a minimal})) $$, then the CONCLUSION is: *every nonempty set has a minimal* (which is axiom of Regularity). Proving the induction hypothesis is easy: either $x$ is a minimal of $u$ (i.e.; $x \cap u =\varnothing$), or there is $x' \in x \cap u$, then we apply $x'$ instead of $y$ and $u$ instead of $z$ in the the *antecedent* of the induction hypothesis and we get $u \text { has a minimal}$

Answer (score 8):

The contrapositive of $\in$-induction says that if $\varphi(x)$ fails for some set $x$, then there is a set $x$ such that $\varphi(y)$ holds for each $y\in x$, but $\varphi(x)$ fails. Now let $a$ be any set, and let $\varphi_a(x)$ be the formula $x\notin a$. Use the contrapositive to show that either $a=0$, or there is an $x\in a$ such that $x\cap a=0$.

Comment: using the same symbol at different quantification is economic but confusing. It would be clearer if we use different symbols, so to rephrase: .... if $\varphi(k)$ fails for some set $k$, then there is a set $x$ such that $\varphi(y)$ holds for each $y \in x$, but $\varphi(x)$ fails.

Comment: @Zuhair: I don’t find that one bit clearer; it just introduces a completely unnecessary symbol. What might actually be slightly clearer for some readers is this: The contrapositive of $\in$-induction says that if $\varphi(x) fails for some $x$, then in particular it fails for some set $x$ such that $\varphi(y)$ holds for each $y\in x$.

Comment: What is clear and what is not, is very subjective. But, it is generally easier to use separate symbols when you have different quantification scopes, otherwise one would confuse quantifications. For a beginner it is easier. This becomes obvious when one works out the last sentence of yours. The proof is otherwise very nice.

Comment: @Zuhair: Of course it’s subjective. The fact remains that what you find obvious, I find invisible. Some 40 years of teaching experience make me think that the change that you suggest is unlikely to make the argument more accessible to students in general, so I see no good reason here to change the name of the variable (or for that matter to worry about quantification) — *except* when experimenting with alternative explanations when helping an individual student who for some reason is having trouble.

Comment: The error comes from quick reading actually. Otherwise there would be no problem if one writes matters down and take care not to confuse quantification scopes. Upon quick reading of your last sentence (which begins from "Now let $a$...") one may confuse matters for $x$ being a parameter running over the whole contrapositive, and so misread matters to $\forall x (x  \in a \implies \forall y \in x (y \not \in a))$, and so hastily conclude that either $a=\emptyset$ or that for *every* $x \in a$ we have $x \cap a=\emptyset$. I think the very beginner might fall a prey to that as well? Anyhow

Answer (score 3):

Define $Unending \ chain$: $$ Unending \ chain (c) \iff \forall m \in c \ [\exists n \in m \ (n \in c)]$$

Define $WF(x)$ $$WF(x) \iff \neg \exists c \ (Unending \ chain (c) \wedge x \in c)$$

Now take any arbitrary set $a$, if every member of $a$ is not a member of some Unending chain (i.e. all are well founded), then clearly $a$ would be well founded!  since if otherwise we'll have an Unending chain $c$ with $a \in c$, but by then there will exist an element $n$ of $a$ such that $n \in c$, but $c$ is an Unending chain, and the existence of such an element $n$ clearly contradicts the condition that all elements of $a$ are not elements of unending chains.

So the antecedent of Epsilon induction is fulfilled for the property $WF$, so all sets fulfill $WF$. Which is Regularity! that is "every Unending chain is empty", i.e. every set is well founded.

Comment: Other than posting what is essentially Andreas Blass' answer, *from nearly five years ago*, only with a contradiction instead of a simple direct proof, is there a point to this answer?

Comment: I find this to be clearer.

Comment: It is indeed clearer, so I managed to verify it: https://github.com/georgydunaev/zfc/blob/master/3_Regularity.v