# Axiom of Foundation (regularity) implies epsilon induction

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to understand why epsilon induction is equivalent to foundation, given the other axioms of ZF.

In another post, it is shown that [epsilon induction implies foundation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452809/epsilon-induction-implies-axiom-of-foundation-or-regularity), and I understand that argument. However, unlike the OP at that question, I am not quite able to show the other way around. I think I'm most of the way there:

**Proof that foundation implies epsilon induction** (not complete)

Imagine towards the contrapositive that epsilon induction doesn't hold. Then we have some formula $\varphi(x)$, and we have that if $\varphi$ is true of all your elements then it must be true for you; and yet, there is some set $s$ for which $\varphi(s)$ is false.

Therefore, $s$ contains an element $s_1$ which does not satisfy $\varphi$, and $s_1$ contains $s_2$ which does not satisfy $\varphi$, and so on.
So that gives us $s_1 \ni s_2 \ni s_3 \ni \cdots$

Except, we can't just define all the $s_k$ one at a time; we better have a way of defining them all at once. In fact, I know that there are models of set theory in which the integers are nonstandard, so that a decreasing ``chain'' of elements exists in the sense that $s_1 \ni s_2 \ni s_3 \ni \cdots$ for as many $s_k$ as you have the patience to define.

So, I think what I am missing is how one uses the axiom of infinity (existence of an inductive set) to somehow define the entire sequence at once, perhaps as a function from an inductive set $I$ to sets that do not satisfy $\varphi$. If we can do that, then I expect we apply the schema of replacement to get the image of that function, and then show that the resulting set does not contain any $\epsilon$-minimal element, hence showing the axiom of foundation is false. But I'm missing an important step.

Comment: Unlike what you say, $\varphi$ is not a sentence, and typically you want it to have more than one free variable.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Right, I meant to say formula. So, to make sure I understand, in the axiom schema of induction as stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon-induction), you are saying P might have either free variables, so as to allow for induction even in the context of other fixed parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\varphi(\cdot)$ satisfies the premise of $\in$-induction, but that we have $s$ such that $\neg\varphi(s)$.

Let $\operatorname{Tr}(s)$ be the transitive closure of $s$ (constructed by using Replacement on $\omega$ to form $\{{\cup}^n s\mid n\in\omega \}$ and then taking its union), and consider $$A=\{x\in \operatorname{Tr}(s)\mid \neg\varphi(x)\}$$

*(Intuition: $A$ is a set such that every element of $A$ contains at least one element of $A$. This is exactly what Foundation says is not allowed to exist. It doesn't give us any* particular *descending $\in$-chain, though we could extract one if Dependent Choice holds either in our model or at the metalevel.)*

Formally: $A$ is nonempty because it contains $s$, so by Foundation there is a $q\in A$ that is disjoint from $A$. Since $\neg\varphi(q)$ and the induction step holds, there must be a $p\in q$ such that $\neg\varphi(p)$. But this $p$ would *also* need to be in $\operatorname{Tr}(s)$, and since $\neg\varphi(p)$ we have $p\in A$. But this contradicts $q$ being disjoint from $A$.

Comment: Thanks Henning for the great answer. I apologize for my clear lack of expertise, but could you say a little more about the construction of the transitive closure? In order to use replacement we need to define $f(n) = \cup^n s$ for each element $n \in \omega$, and in order to define $f$ we need to define it recursively. But how do I define it recursively without the axiom of induction? (The rest of the answer is clear!)

Comment: @6005: You can say that $u=\cup^n s$ iff there exists a $g$ such that (1) $g$ is a function with domain $n^+$, (2) $g(0)=s$, (3) for all $k\in n$ it holds that $g(k^+)=\cup g(k)$, and (4) $u=g(k)$. To use Replacement you need to show that this defines $u$ uniquely, but that can be done by plain old mathematical induction on $n$ -- and mathematical induction is implicit in defining $\omega$ as the intersection of all inductive sets. (Otherwise the $n\in\omega$ for which there _is_ exactly one valid $u$ would constitute a smaller inductive set, contradicting that definition).