# Is it possible to prove Regularity with Transfinite Induction only?

Tags: set-theory, foundations, transfinite-induction

Let us assume that we have only statement of transfinite induction. (And maybe some other well-know axioms)
My question: "**Is it possible to derive from it a regularity axiom as a theorem?**".

Some of my thoughts:

Definition 1: 
$S(x):=(\exists a.a\in x)\rightarrow (\exists y\in x . \neg \exists z\in y.z\in x)$

Main theorem: $\forall x. S(x)$.

Proof: Firstly, apply transfinite induction. Now we need to show that $\forall x. \big((\forall z\in x.S(z))\rightarrow S(x)\big)$.

In order to prove it, let's start a proof by contradiction.
Assume that there exists M such that $(\forall z\in M.S(z))\land \neg S(M)$. Now we need to prove a false. ... (I got stuck here.)

It may be useful to prove lemma like $z\in M \land S(M) \rightarrow S(z)$. (That's because we would immediately get a desired contradiction.)

But I don't know whether it is true. Any comments are welcome.

**Edited:**

I am currently verifying this theorem in coq-contrib/zfc library and obtain the next situation. (I think I properly followed Andreas' instructions.)

Now we have $z\in u$, $z\in x$, $x\in u$, $(\mbox{hyp} : \forall y \in x .P (y))$. We also have proved $P[z/x]$, where $P$ is your LaTeX formula.(by IndHyp). Our aim is to prove False from this context. What are the next steps?

**Edited 2:**

Self-contained code of the unfinished(!) theorem may be found here:
https://gist.github.com/georgydunaev/f24883f05ebaadb8c658cf53858646da

**Edited 3 (*final*):**
I've wrote a full solution here:
https://github.com/georgydunaev/zfc/blob/master/3_Regularity.v

Comment: Regularity is equivalent to $\in$-induction. Namely if $\varphi(x)$ defines a class and $(\forall y(y\in x\rightarrow\varphi(y))\rightarrow\varphi(x)$, then $\forall x\varphi(x)$.

Comment: Yes, Asaf, thanks. That's exactly what I am trying to prove and say. Now I see the similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452809/epsilon-induction-implies-axiom-of-foundation-or-regularity.

Comment: It's embarassing, but even with answers from that question, I can't construct the proof. Any other references are welcome.

Comment: You should probably [edit] your question to reflect that changes.

Comment: Transfinite induction is a statement about ordinals. Is that what you mean, or do you mean $\epsilon$-induction, as indicated by Asaf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove, by $\in$-induction on $x$, that all sets $x$ have the following property.
$$
\forall u\,\big(x\in u\implies (\exists y\in u)(\forall z\in u)\,z\notin y)\big).
$$
That is, every set $u$ that contains $x$ also contains an $\in$-minimal member. The idea of the proof is that, if $x$ is not $\in$-minimal in $u$, then the counterexample to minimality is a member of $x$ and therefore subject to the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Now we have z\in u, z\in x, x\in u, hyp : \forall y, y \in xi -> P y. We also have proved P[z/x], where P is your LaTeX formula.(by IndHyp). Our aim is to prove False from this context. What are the next steps?

Comment: You have $P[z/x]$, i.e., every set that contains $z$ also contains an $\in$-minimal member. And you have $z\in u$. So $u$ has an $\in$-minimal member.

Comment: I spent several hours trying to prove it using your method and didn't succeed. I am afraid there may be something misleading... Anyway, I have easily proved and verified your statement P and regularity axiom through the Zuhair's proof. It can be found here: https://github.com/georgydunaev/zfc/blob/master/3_Regularity.v

Comment: I thought my last comment completed the proof. After all, that part is just a classic syllogism. Premise 1: All sets containing $z$ have minimal members. Premise 2: $u$ is a set containing $z$. Conclusion: Therefore $u$ has a minimal member. Both of the premises are among the facts you already knew, according to your previous comment, so what more is needed?

Comment: Thanks a lot, nothing is needed. (My language skills are not very good, so I should say it explicitly.)